# What could be the reason for SQL Server Express to roll back a database to a previous state?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express, data-loss, terminal-server

I have some very strange problems. I have an application running on Windows 2003 terminal server from multiple clients. The application uses SQL Server 2008 Express as its database.

Yesterday, I connected to the app, closed some sessions on the server that were not responding, and to my surprise, I saw that some data was missing from the database. After a futher search I found that all the database changes made from last week were lost.

It's like the database rolled back all the changes, and returned to the state of one week ago! I can confirm that all the changes were lost. In fact I have inserted a record into a table with `identity_insert ON` (to manually insert an ID on an autonumeric col) and that record is missing, so there is no way this is a program failure.

Does anyone have any idea of what could have happend here?

**EDIT**

I have a suspect: could a transaction initiated by a session stays in a unconfirmed state for one week, retain all the database changes and when I close the session rollback all the changes made?

**EDIT II**

Find this on log:
[image: Log]

Comment: Database has been restored from a backup, or if it's running on a virtual server, the entire virtual machine has been restored?

Comment: Thanks. No to both questions.

Comment: Pretty sure this is OT for Stack Overflow (there's no programming issue here). Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "so there is no way this is a program failure." The program could have deleted the record.

Comment: There's absolutely no way SQL Server can roll itself back to a previous state. It has to be a database restore, server restore or just a file restore.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm none of the obove. Please see my Update.

Comment: A transaction could be open for a week but would likely lock that row and cause you other problems. Even without the locking the only thing that would get rolled back would be changes made in that connection.

Comment: ok. So all the client are runnin my App from terminal server. The transaction is initiated by a DLL, wich is shared from all the session. If the connection initiate the transaction, could involve all changes made to the database, even through direct SQL updates over the database with SQL management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server never rolls back a database to a previous state (like this). The database was restored, or the entire disk/VM was rolled back, or DML was executed to create the impression that a rollback happened (but really didn't). Maybe someone executed a sync tool in the wrong direction.

The question does not have information that allows for finding the problem. But it certainly isn't SQL Server rolling back a database.

You can try examining the log using `fn_dblog`.

Comment: Also check the server log to determine if database has been restored.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that database was not restored (there is no backup to restore from either). Please see my update.

Comment: @ericpap yes, transactions can stay open forever. However if you are not using NOLOCK/RU other transactions would not see that data. SSMS wouldn't show you the uncommitted rows. But SSMS can be set to use RU... Check that.

Comment: Yes I understand. Data where visible through my app and SSMS, so I suppose transaction have to be commited. I don't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: Examine the log and look for rollback log records. You can then look at the contents of the transaction that was rolled by by its ID. Maybe you'll find that there is one huge tran that spans one week and that was killed.

Comment: Thanks! Excelent tip. Can you help me on how to examine the log a find that on SQL Express?

Comment: Just run that function and look at what it returns. It's kind of obvious. If not ask a new question with sample data.

Comment: So, and find one transaction but it doesn't appear to be related with my problem. Also find a "recovery" in the log, but don't know exactly what it means. Can you give it a look on my update?

Comment: That's the server log, not the transaction log. Query fn_dblog.

Answer (score 0):

From the log it looks like the server has only just started up after a reboot or service restart.

If a database is not cleanly shut down then the database can be left with partially applied transactions. If this happens then the database is recovered on start up.

Any transactions that are incomplete are rolled back. Committed transactions that were not yet applied are rolled forwards. How long this recovery takes depends on the size of the transactions in the log that have not yet been applied to the database.

The transactions may not show up in the log after they have been rolled back following a crash. This depends upon their location in the log and the databases's recovery mode.

- If the transaction is at the end of the log it is likely the log will just be rolled back and the transaction removed.
- If the transaction is in the middle of the log you might see a LOP_ABORT_XACT in the log.
- When using simple recovery there is a good chance the log will be cleared after recovery (since the logs are only kept until the transactions are committed).

See [Are log records removed from ldf file for rollbacks?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/03/22/are-log-records-removed-from-ldf-file-for-rollbacks.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems that the problem happend just after an  inexpected system reboot . But i cannot seem to find a way to see is a transaction was rolled back. I try fn_dblog but it doens't seem to be any drop transaction.